# how can i host a file in Angular with routing?

Tags: angular, routes

lets say i have a pdf file that i want to host on my angular site (v7). I have it in my wwwroot folder and when trying to route to that folder & file via angular routing, i get an error that the route does not exist

for example
file is located in `wwwroot/sub/file.pdf`
my route has the path, lets say `/files/file.pdf`. this would be the endpoint on my site `www.example.com/files/file.pdf`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'files/file.pdf', //this is when a user types www.example.com/files/file.pdf
    redirectTo: '/sub/file.pdf' //this is where the file is stored in wwwroot
  }
];
```

i have tested my path and redirected to a component, works fine.

that component is in the app folder tho, which is totally separate than the wwwroot folder. I don't care where the file is located, i'll move it to the app folder if needed, but i've tried that and can't seem to get it to work either.

Since the wwwroot and app folder are 2 separate folders, i don't know how to get to app from wwwroot. my first thoughts are from wwwroot aka `www.example.com` to go up a level `../` and then into `app/src/...` of course this didn't work either and i dont think you can go above the wwwroot folder in the structure this way.

how can i serve this file from my wwwroot folder (or anywhere else) on my angular site?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify the project's `assets` configuration in the angular.json file in order to include static files with your application deployment. Refer to the documentation at: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#assets-configuration in order to include files via a glob pattern.

In your case, the configuration might look like:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            ...
            "assets": [
              ...
              './files/**/*'
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, link to the file as you would for downloading a file from the root of your website: `<a href="/files/file.pdf">Download</a>`.